# Document Prints Halfway Down Page When Printing HTML from Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Using document.write() I'm printing the contents of an object, formatted for the printer.  The text will only print starting halfway down the page.

I can print the screen directly without this problem, so it leads me to think that I'm formatting something incorrectly, but I've never done this before and I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my print function.

```
    let popupWin: any;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>${this.editPla.name}</title>
        <style></style>
      </head>
      <body onload="window.print();window.close()">
        <table>
          ${values[0]}
          ${values[1]}
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

Here is a short sample of the string contained in the values variable (the actual string is quite long):

```
      <tr style="width:100%;">
        <td style="height:5px;width:75px; border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Foo</td>
        <td style="height:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Bar</td><br>
        <td style="height:5px;width:75px; border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Foo</td>
        <td style="height:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Bar</td><br>
        <td style="height:5px;width:75px; border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Foo</td>
        <td style="height:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Bar</td><br>
        <td style="height:5px;width:75px; border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Foo</td>
        <td style="height:5px;border-bottom:1px dotted #777;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;">Bar</td><br>
      </tr>
```

My results are as shown: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1szQ-a3-KEVjYFhQfHDEJPTXKnG9-5m8S/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The answer to this issue is that I foolishly insterted a `<br>` tag at the end of each  row.  Once removed, the documents prints as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good from what you did post.  You don't show how this is called however.

When this is called, is it in a DIV with vertical alignment modified??

It looks like your window is loading with vertical alignment in the middle instead of top.
If you are passing "this" it can pass(inherit) the modifications

try adding a style to the body tag to align it to the top

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Since I posted, I've found that if I remove the <table></table> wrapping ${values[0]} & ${values[1]} in the print function that the printing will align with the top of the page, but of course I lose all table styling.  I don't understand why this is the case.